# Getting "Unable to find resource, invalid path in url." after creating the selenium grid hub

Tags: selenium-grid

Getting "Unable to find resource, invalid path in url." after creating the selenium grid hub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTs9Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Java 8+ when starting the Selenium Grid 3.x onward.
In my case of Selenium Grid 4.7.1 I used Java 11, it was giving the error you described with Java 8.